# How to stich images together in java

Tags: java, image-processing

So the problem is as follows i want to make a java application that can create tickets for events like concerts and such. I would like the tickets to be either a jpg or a pdf document and i want to have qr codes on them besides other information. I've already figured out some libraries that can generate the codes but i have no idea how to go about adding them on the tickets.If there are existing libraries for doing tasks exactly like this i would be very happy to know them.

Currently im using the ZXing qr generator library but im also having trouble getting it to generate the codes in different file format's and the only one that seems to work currently for me is the jpg format.

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is use a `BufferedImage` and simply paint the other elements directly onto it - see the [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for more details

Comment: You might consider having a look at [Generating Barcodes and QR Codes in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generating-barcodes-qr-codes); [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen); [Barcode4J](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/) for the barcodes

Comment: You can look at [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en) for PDF generation, but I'd encourage you to look at [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) instead (which uses iText), while it has a step learning curve, it's ability to export to a number of different formats makes it worth the time to learn

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing requires a lot of time and effort.

You could go the "manual" approach and do all the work yourself, while achievable and generally quick, it can become complicated very quickly and difficult to maintain.

The following makes use of both [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) and ZXing, for comparisions.  I used Maven to manage the dependencies and you'll need to add...

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kenglxn.qrgen</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

to your `pom.xml` file.

I just went online and "stole" a basic layout to replicate...

[image: Example]

```
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.glxn.qrgen.javase.QRCode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private double fullWidth = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(16.75, 300);
    private double fullHeight = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(6.75, 300);

    private int intFullWidth = (int) Math.ceil(fullWidth);
    private int intFullHeight = (int) Math.ceil(fullHeight);

    private double mainSectionWidth = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(13.5, 300);
    private double stubSectionWidth = fullWidth - mainSectionWidth;

    private double zipperWidth = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(0.1, 300.0);

    private double qrCodeSize = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(2.0, 300.0);

    private double borderSize = PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(0.45, 300);

    private Font mainFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    private float artistFontSize = 128;
    private float venuFontSize = 82;
    private float messageFontSize = 48;

    private String artistName = "Super Star";
    private String venuName = "Some place";
    private String message = "You owe me money";

    private DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy");
    private DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    private LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    private BufferedImage qrCode;

    private String section = "C";
    private String row = "24";
    private String seat = "16";

    public Main() {
        String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n"
                + " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,\n"
                + " quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

        try {
            qrCode = generateZXingQRCodeImage(text, qrCodeSize);
//            qrCode = generateQRGenCodeImage(text, qrCodeSize);

            BufferedImage baseImage = ImageSupport.createCompatibleImage(intFullWidth, intFullHeight, ImageSupport.Transparancy.OPAQUE);
            Graphics2D g2d = baseImage.createGraphics();
            applyQualitySettings(g2d);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, intFullWidth, intFullHeight);
            paintMainSection(g2d);
            paintStubSection(g2d);
            paintZipper(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(baseImage, "png", new File("Ticket.png"));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(baseImage)));

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected int ceil(double value) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(value);
    }

    protected void applyQualitySettings(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    }

    protected void paintMainSection(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int width = ceil(mainSectionWidth);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, intFullHeight);

        int x = ceil(borderSize);
        int y = ceil(borderSize);
        width = width - (x * 2);
        int height = intFullHeight - (y * 2);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        g2d.translate(x, y);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // >> Ariest name
        int avaliableHeight = (int) (height * 0.5);
        Font artiestFont = mainFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, artistFontSize);
        g2d.setFont(artiestFont);
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        x = (width - fm.stringWidth(artistName)) / 2;
        y = (avaliableHeight - fm.getHeight()) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(artistName, x, y + fm.getAscent());
        // << Ariest name

        // >> Venu details
        g2d.translate(0, avaliableHeight);
        avaliableHeight = height - avaliableHeight;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Font venuFont = mainFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, venuFontSize);
        g2d.setFont(venuFont);
        fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        y = 0;
        g2d.drawString(dateFormatter.format(dateTime), ceil(borderSize), y + fm.getAscent());

        x = width / 2;
        g2d.drawString(timeFormatter.format(dateTime), x, y + fm.getAscent());

        y += fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(venuName, ceil(borderSize), y + fm.getAscent());

        y += fm.getHeight();
        int remainingHeight = avaliableHeight - y;

        Font messageFont = mainFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, messageFontSize);
        g2d.setFont(messageFont);
        fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        x = (width - fm.stringWidth(message)) / 2;
        y = y + ((remainingHeight - fm.getHeight())) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(message, x, y + fm.getAscent());

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    protected void paintStubSection(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int width = ceil(stubSectionWidth);
        g2d.translate(intFullWidth - width, 0);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, intFullHeight);

        int x = ceil(borderSize);
        int y = ceil(borderSize);
        width = width - (x * 2);
        int height = intFullHeight - (y * 2);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        g2d.translate(x, y);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        x = (width - qrCode.getWidth()) / 2;
        y = height - qrCode.getHeight() - ceil(borderSize);

        g2d.drawImage(qrCode, x, y, null);

        //int remainingHeight = height - y - ceil(borderSize) * 2;
        g2d.translate(0, ceil(borderSize));

        Font plainFont = mainFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, messageFontSize);
        Font boldFont = mainFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, messageFontSize);

        FontMetrics plainFM = g2d.getFontMetrics(plainFont);
        FontMetrics boldFM = g2d.getFontMetrics(boldFont);

        g2d.setFont(plainFont);
        String text = "Section";
        x = (width - plainFM.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        y = 0;
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

        y += plainFM.getHeight();

        g2d.setFont(boldFont);
        x = (width - boldFM.stringWidth(section)) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(section, x, y);

        y += boldFM.getHeight();
        int avaliableWidth = width / 2;

        g2d.setFont(plainFont);
        text = "Row";
        x = (avaliableWidth - plainFM.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

        text = "SEAT";
        x = avaliableWidth + (avaliableWidth - plainFM.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

        y += plainFM.getHeight();

        g2d.setFont(boldFont);
        text = row;
        x = (avaliableWidth - boldFM.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

        text = seat;
        x = avaliableWidth + (avaliableWidth - boldFM.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    protected void paintZipper(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();

        float dash[] = {(float) PrintSupport.cmsToPixel(0.15, 300)};
        BasicStroke dashedStroke = new BasicStroke((float) zipperWidth, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 10f, dash, 0.0f);
        g2d.setStroke(dashedStroke);

        g2d.translate(mainSectionWidth, 0);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 0, intFullHeight));

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateZXingQRCodeImage(String barcodeText, double size) throws Exception {
        QRCodeWriter barcodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix
                = barcodeWriter.encode(barcodeText, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, (int) Math.ceil(size), (int) Math.ceil(size));

        return MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
    }

    public static BufferedImage generateQRGenCodeImage(String barcodeText, double size) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = QRCode
                .from(barcodeText)
                .withSize((int) Math.ceil(size), (int) Math.ceil(size))
                .stream();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());

        return ImageIO.read(bis);
    }

    public class ImageSupport {

        public static enum Transparancy {
            OPAQUE(Transparency.OPAQUE), BITMASK(Transparency.OPAQUE), TRANSLUCENT(Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);

            private int value;

            private Transparancy(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }
        }

        public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
            BufferedImage target = createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getTransparency());
            Graphics2D g2d = target.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g2d.dispose();
            return target;
        }

        public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, Transparancy transparancy) {
            return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparancy.getValue());
        }

        protected static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
            return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        }

        public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
            return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        }
    }

    public class PrintSupport {
        // The number of CMs per Inch
        public static final double CM_PER_INCH = 0.393700787d;
        // The number of Inches per CMs
        public static final double INCH_PER_CM = 2.545d;
        // The number of Inches per mm's
        public static final double INCH_PER_MM = 25.45d;

        /**
         * Converts the given pixels to cm's based on the supplied DPI
         *
         * @param pixels
         * @param dpi
         * @return
         */
        public static double pixelsToCms(double pixels, double dpi) {
            return inchesToCms(pixels / dpi);
        }

        /**
         * Converts the given cm's to pixels based on the supplied DPI
         *
         * @param cms
         * @param dpi
         * @return
         */
        public static double cmsToPixel(double cms, double dpi) {
            return cmToInches(cms) * dpi;
        }

        /**
         * Converts the given cm's to inches
         *
         * @param cms
         * @return
         */
        public static double cmToInches(double cms) {
            return cms * CM_PER_INCH;
        }

        /**
         * Converts the given inches to cm's
         *
         * @param inch
         * @return
         */
        public static double inchesToCms(double inch) {
            return inch * INCH_PER_CM;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, imagine your "awesome" graphical design comes back to you and wants to start moving some of the text around, change the font and sizes, probably wants some super awesome back ground effects.

After you finish burying their body, understand how hard it would to be modify the above example.  Now you could spend a lot of time generating dynamic code paths, maybe rendering sections of the layout to images to make it easier to handle and tearing your hair out over supporting multiple line text and/or dynamic font re-sizing, or, you could spend your time learning something like [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) which do most of the heavy lifting for you and also supports exporting the result to the printer, PDF, Word, Excel, HTML ... what ever!

> What's with `PrinterSupport`

Okay, this is one of those "wonderful" side effects.  Java's print APIs generally working at 72dpi as there input, so you need to do a lot of conversions to make it support things like high resolution printers (300dpi for example).  These APIs basically does the work automatically, so, hopefully , this will look nice when it's printed.

> But what about PDF?

Again, see JasperReports, if you "must" do it by hand, [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en) is pretty much the only solution you have